# Array argument issues for Sumif

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, range, sumifs

I'm trying to make the following formula work and it's giving me "Array arguments to SUMIFS are of different size."

```
=SUMIFS(ChronologicalExpenditures!I2:I995, ChronologicalExpenditures!N3:N, "*"&H2&"*", ChronologicalExpenditures!B3:B, "Expenditure, Contractor")
```

Basically, I want to add the values in "ChronologicalExpenditures!I2:I995" together, ONLY if "ChronologicalExpenditures!N3:N" is equal to "*"&H2&"*" And "ChronologicalExpenditures!B3:B" is equal to "Expenditure, Contractor".

So basically sum (column A) together, but only if (column B) = (Contents of cell X) and (Column C) = "Sample text"

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: all ranges needs to have a same hight / size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=SUMIFS(ChronologicalExpenditures!I2:I, 
        ChronologicalExpenditures!N2:N, "*"&H2&"*", 
        ChronologicalExpenditures!B2:B, "Expenditure, Contractor")
```